# Find perimeter of flag...

Tags: geometry

[image]

I took a practice SAT test, and I didn't do as well on the math portion as I was hoping to. I ran into a problem like this (not geometry, but one that took me too much time) in each section and didn't have time to check my work..

Anyway, the problem shows a flag like this (not drawn to proportion) and gives the following information: the flag is made of two identical, intersecting equilateral triangles. All three line segments on the right hand side are 10 inches long.

It asks for the perimeter of the flag...

I didn't figure out how to solve the problem until after I had taken the test and thought about it. It took me too long to realize that the length of the sides of the larger triangles was 20 inches. I still don't have a mathematical basis for knowing that, it just logically made sense.

What conclusions should I have made upon seeing the flag and reading the information? What would have been the best way to solve this?

Comment: What you saw a little too late is exactly the way you were intended to solve the problem. If each segment has length $10$, then since a side of the triangle is made up of two segments, the side is $20$. Unfortunately, the SAT (and too many tests, even at the university level) are tests of quickness, not of ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the first tip I give to any student about the SAT math portion:

> Stop reading the question when you get to the first comma.

*Many* SAT math problems are in the form

**"If ...** *(statement about the picture, $x,y,z$, etc)* ....., **then what is.....?**

And the question (which is *after* the comma) usually requires more than one step to complete.

**Example:** "If $(x + y)^2 = 121 \ \ $ and  $xy = -13$, then what is the value of $x^2 + y^2$ ?"

This problem can be tricky if we focus on the question (i.e. on directly determining the value of $x^2 + y^2$). Instead, let's stop when we get to the comma.

So we have $(x + y)^2 = 121$ and ... well, let's work with that!

$(x + y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy$, by FOIL-ing/distributive property/etc, and this equals $121$. So $$(x+y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy = 121$$
Since $xy = -13$, we can substitute this in, to get: $$x^2 + y^2 + 2(-13) = 121$$ From this you should be able to see the answer.

---

Like I said, *many* SAT math problems are like this: They give data in the "if" part of the question, sufficient to draw *some* conclusion(s), and then ask for a conclusion that may be 2-3 steps beyond what you can immediately see.

The easiest way to overcome this is to *Stop reading at the comma!*

Comment: ARGGG. I figured I would try to solve this as practice, and went the completely wrong direction. I took the root of both sides and got `x+y = +- 11`... Any suggestions on not doing things like that?

Comment: By choosing $121$, I was trying to be somewhat deceptive... of course, *that's what the testmakers do!!* It's not terrible that you tried to take square roots, but if something doesn't pop into your head after looking at $\pm 1$ and the $-13$ for a while, try a different route. Also, play sudoku. Seriously.

Comment: I overplayed Sudoku and started playing Kenken, and then started playing the 6x6 kenken's without the candidate numbers and then got bored. I respect the deceptiveness of the tests though. Without it, too many people would get good scores and destroy the point of the SAT.

Comment: Another example of the "deception"... let's say that an SAT math question was "Add up all the integers from 1 to ___". I would say that of the options for n = 6, 40, or 1000, the testmakers are *most likely* to have n = 40, since n = 6 is too easy and n = 1000 is "too hard" (in the sense that you would never manually add up all those numbers, but would look for - and probably discover - a shortcut). Choosing a middle-ground number like 40 will have some people type it all into their calculator and waste a couple minutes...

Comment: For which the shortcut would be to multiply by the limit + 1 and then divide by 2, right?

Answer (score 2):

You are right that the side of the triangles is 20 inches, as it is made up of two 10 inch segments.  The triangles are equilateral, so all the sides are 20 inches.  Because all the angles are 60 degrees, the small triangle is equilateral, too, and has a side of 10 inches.  The total perimeter is then two 20 inch long sides, the two 10 inch short sides on the left, and the given 30 inch segment on the right, for a total of 90 inches.

Comment: God I hate geometry for this very reason. I always miss such trivial things as your first statement. Thanks for answering!